# Login Form and Add Tabpages into Main Form TabControls

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 forms that are the Login_Form, Main_Form and I also have a Form that always display a datagridview.

Here is the Main Form:
[image: Main Form]

Here is the Login Form
[image: Login Form]

Here is the Show User Data Form
[image: Show User Data Form]

This is the Login Button Click code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(this.txtusername.Text =="" || this.txtpassword.Text =="")
    {
        this.lblserverstatus.Text = "Can not be null";
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblserverstatus.Text = "running login...";

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE acc = '" + txtusername.Text + "' AND pw = '" + txtpassword.Text + "'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    this.lblserverstatus.Text = "Login Successful";
                    UserName = txtusername.Text;
                    Password = txtpassword.Text;
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.lblserverstatus.Text = "Login fail";
                DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Main_Form Code

```
public Main_Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DialogResult result;
    using (var Login_Form = new Login_Form())
    {
        result = Login_Form.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var username = Login_Form.UserName;
            var password = Login_Form.Password;
            //this.lblpw.Text = password;
            //this.lblusername.Text = username;
            this.QueryLoginedUserData(username, password);
            MessageBox.Show(username + " Success Login");
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(new main_tab(new user_data()));
        }
        else
        {
            result = DialogResult.No;
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the program, it will run the Main_Form and will call Login_Form to login. But if I do it once again while I haven't closed the program. It can't add more tabpages into the Main_Form tabcontrols. What Events do I need to use or what can I do in this situation?

The flow of this program is:

Run Program->Login->Show data in the datagridview on the tabpages which name userID->Main_Form click login again with a different user->Add Tabpages which name is the userID and show the data in the datagridview on the tabpages-> again

Comment: Please add something like this after adding a tab page `tabControl1.TabPages.Referesh()` or `tabControl1.TabPages.Update()`.

Comment: "do it once again" would require running the Main_Form constructor again.  That is unlikely to be useful, a UI normally only has one main form.  Since there is only ever one, consider that you can declare a static Instance property that returns the one-and-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see you call your `Login form` from your `Main form` where tabs are located.

If that is the case then this is simple.

Add `public void AddTab()` function inside `MainForm` with some code

```
public void AddTab(string passedData)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is example.\nPassed data is: " + passedData + "\nThis function is ran on " + this.Text + " form");
    //Here write adding tab function
}
```

Then inside `Login` form create one more `Constructor` which requires your `MainForm` class. When you pass it you will be able to access all `public` objects from `MainForm` and since we created `public void AddTab(string passedData)` we will be able to use that function.

```
public partial class YourLoginForm
{
    private MainForm mf;

    //This is standard constructor
    public YourLoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    //This is new constructor
    public YourLoginForm(MainForm form)
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        mf = form; //Setting our globally accessible variable (within this class) to reference of passed form (main form)
    }

    private void LoginButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mf.AddTab("I have passed this string"); //Accessing public void from main form.
    }
}
```